# Comparing two multidimensional object arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am struggling to compare 2 mufti-dimensional object arrays as follows and adding the difference to a empty array.

**Array1**

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#393 (1) { 
       ["ID"]=> 
       string(3) "433" 
  } 
}
```

**Array 2**

```
array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#386 (1) { 
       ["ID"]=> 
       string(3) "433" 
  } 
}
```

So far I have used the following function:

```
function compare_arrays($Array1, $Array2){

$result = array();
    foreach ($Array2 as $index => $newItem) {
    foreach ($Array1 as $oldItem) {             
    if($Array2['ID'] === $oldItem['ID'])
    {
       $result[] = $index;
    }
  }                     
}               

return $result;
}
```

I am getting the following error?

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Can somebody please guide me as where I am going wrong? Or if there is a different simpler approach?

**FIX**

Code fixed as per Adeel and Fabricator

Had to create a special class to create a blank object and then assign the
value to it.

```
function compare_arrays($para1, $para2){
    $result = array();
            /*Special class to create a blank object*/
    $data = new stdClass();

    foreach ($para2 as $index => $newItem) {
        foreach ($para1 as $oldItem) {      
            $test2 = $oldItem->ID;
            if($newItem->ID === $oldItem->ID)
            {
                $data->ID = $newItem->ID;

                $result[] = $data;                  
                var_dump($results);
            }
        }                       
    }               
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: have you tried passing by reference?

Comment: use `->ID` instead of `['ID']`?

Comment: and `$Array2['ID']` should be `$newItem->ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access this std class object you need to access it like this `$Array2->ID`
you are accessing it like an array therefore this error pops up.